# Speed up MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, wordpress

I have a Wordpress Woocommerce store using WP All Import Pro to run automatic imports on a 15 minute cronjob schedule. It's usually trying to update 400 to 500 items from our supplier every 15 minutes. MariaDB speed is not fast enough to finish the update within the 15 minutes. Any help would be appreciated!

**Server Info**

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L v2 @ 2.40GHz

4 cpu

8G ram

80G SSD drive

Updated `my.cnf` file

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking

key_buffer              = 4M
max_allowed_packet      = 10M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
open_files_limit        = 30000
key_buffer_size         = 20M
myisam-recover          = BACKUP
max_connections         = 45
max_user_connections    = 15

query_cache_type        = 1
query_cache_limit       = 70M
query_cache_size        = 40M

log_error               = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 75M

#
# * InnoDB
#
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 1
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 820M
innodb_log_file_size            = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 1M

join_buffer_size                = 128M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 4M
max_allowed_packet              = 20M

tmp_table_size                  = 75M
max_heap_table_size             = 75M

table_open_cache                = 4500
thread_cache_size               = 25

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M


# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT     'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT     'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=135552 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4     COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3281739 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4     COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here are my mysqltunner.pl updated results, what adjustments would you suggest?

```
[OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.5.2 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.0.20-MariaDB-0+deb8u1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MyISAM 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 816M (Tables: 240)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 2M (Tables: 95)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 13

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There is no anonymous account in all database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There is 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 14s (807 q [57.643 qps], 134 conn, TX: 3M, RX: 138K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 1.1G global + 134.3M per thread (45 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.5G (18.68% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 7.0G (89.16% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/807)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 6% (3/45)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/134)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 23.6% (205 cached / 870 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 146 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 9% (20 on disk / 214 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 97% (3 created / 134 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 150% (187 open / 124 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (246/30K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (687 immediate / 687 locks)

-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 19.1% (4M used / 20M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 20.0M/561.0K

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 820.0M/816.9M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 15.80% (8293 used/ 52479 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.71% (1899945 hits/ 1905411 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
```

Comment: Please post your table structures for the tables involved in the update - SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G. I find it hard to believe that MariaDB (or MySQL) can't handle 500 updates in 15 minutes on an SSD drive. In fact I'd be surprised if you couldn't get updates that fast on stone tablets! :-)

Comment: I added the CREATE TABLE info to my question. Thanks

Comment: Can you show some "average update" query too? MariaDB 10 can even EXPLAIN updates so that might come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with mysqltuner script.

```
#Init tips
#Check your logs size, numbers of log.
#check database fragmentation
#check your numbers of logs in dir.
#set to size from key_buffer_size to 512M minimun
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
###################
# Your can use personalized mount point (for example on a SSD Disk)
###################
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
###################
#Bad path? the dir is /usr/share/mysql/$LANG . Bad path cause redundand i/o
###################
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
###################
#MyISAM parameter?
#if not use MyISAM set to 4M
###################
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
open_files_limit=30000
###################
#minimun key_buffer_size to 512M.
#Important
###################
key_buffer_size = 32M
###################
# Not use MyISAM parameter if your only use InnoDB
###################
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
myisam-recover         = BACKUP

max_connections=100
max_user_connections = 50
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit   = 4M
###################
#need more cache (4M cache top), >128MB 
###################
query_cache_size        = 64M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size        = 100M
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
###################
# Remove slow log if you server is PRODUCTION.
###################
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log      = 1
long_query_time = 2
###################
# Generate big logs. CHECK YOUR LOG SIZE
###################
log_queries_not_using_indexes

# * InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
###################
# If your DB is tiny, 2GB is fat configuration.
###################
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size=128M
read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
max_allowed_packet = 20M
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_open_cache = 7500
thread_cache_size = 25
```

I view excesive parameters...
read this article (Percona ) : https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/

Comment: pata_de_jaguar, can you take another look. I updated my.cnf & mysqltuner output.

Comment: @Pop you get better performance or the problem is persistent?. Check the PHP/Apache/NGIX configuration...

Comment: performance is better but still not there. I'm going to work on PHP/Apache now.